# Netbeans, generated code, and svn

Tags: svn, netbeans

We have a netbeans project that has an xsd that we use to create a wsdl and we use the wsdl to create a webservice.  Since we are using types in our xsd jaxb is used and one of our webservice methods looks like this:

```
public void someMethod( org.netbeans.xml.schema.line.Line x )...
```

So that leaves us a problem with subversion since the Line objects are generated by netbeans.  So we want to do is either tell netbeans to place the files inside of the project?  Or tell netbeans that we will generate the jaxb code and that they should use our classes when the webservice calls are processed?  How can we accomplish one of these, what are some other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have approx. two choices

1. have all the generated files in subversion or
2. make sure that file generation is fully automated

Not sure how easily 2. can be be done with netbeans, but it's the way I'd recommend as commits don't spread all over the place after you've changed one line in one file.  Additionally you don't have to worry about "did I update the webservice, or did I just update the xsd?".

OTOH, subversion doesn't care if some editor updated lots of files - it simply makes sure the data gets into the repo.

The important part is to **not** have a manual procedure for building your project.  Fully automated == good.

Answer (score 1):

Since Netbeans 6.7 generated files are automatically marked as such, 
and Netbeans doesn't use versioning tools (Subversion, Mercurial, ...) on them.

[**Search here**](http://www.netbeans.org/community/releases/67/) for "Generated source".

It is now even possible to define custom ant task which do something 
inside generated directories, let's say, every time you perform **clean/build**.